# Install Postgresql 9.4 with Puppet

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, puppet

I would like to let Puppet manage Postgresql 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I have install the https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql module and configured it like this for 9.3:

`class { 'postgresql::globals':
      encoding => 'UTF8',
      locale  => 'en_US',
      manage_package_repo => true,
      version => '9.3',
    }`

This works... But when I change it to `version => '9.4'` I get:

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: pick(): must receive at least one non empty value at /etc/puppet/modules/postgresql/manifests/globals.pp:109 on node`

As far as I understand - I configured the module to use the apt.postgresql.org repository - and I assumed it should be able to use the 9.4 release.

Any hints why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
postgis_version     => '2.1',
```

was missing :S

Comment: That's weird, as the class should be [picking the right postgis_version](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-postgresql/blob/8dbf982b627e0df16bc2ecc2635b5d86d0bf0f55/manifests/globals.pp#L105-L117) for '9.4'

Comment: Probably related to the fact - that Ubuntu 14.04 only has the 9.3 Version as official release... Fixed it for me...